# В чем моя ошибка при глубокой вложеной связи?

Tags: yii2

собственно вот код

```
$titleCat=FrontendSetup::findOne(['key_setup'=>'recomented']);
$recomented=Category::find()->where(['name'=>$titleCat->value])->with('goods','goods.images','goods.prise','goods.addfeilds','goods.ratingCountAggregation','goods.ratingSumAggregation')->all();

if(isset($recomented)) {
    foreach ($recomented as $rec){
        var_dump($rec->goods);
    }
}
```

выдает такую ошибку

> common\models\Category has no relation named "images". ↵ Caused by:
>   Unknown Method – yii\base\UnknownMethodException Calling unknown
>   method: common\models\Category::getimages()
>
> in /var/www/magaz.lc/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Component.php at line
>   285

в чем ошибка не подскажите?

Comment: Казалось бы куда еще проще, все написано, просто читай. Нашим людям же нужно ткнуть носом как котенка)

Comment: @Makarenko_I_V ткните разве не для этого этот сайт создан ?

Comment: Много вопросов не о чем. Ваш можно интерпретировать, как переведите пожайлусто на русский язык. А это к теме SO не относится. @zhukov-roman уже ткнул.

Comment: @Makarenko_I_V вы видимо не заметили, что я его тоже в документацию ткнул.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Написано же:

```
common\models\Category has no relation named "images"
```

Что означает:

```
common\models\Category не имеет связи с именем "images"
```

Вам необходимо создать AR-связь, подобно этой:

```
class Category extends ActiveRecord
{
    // ...

    public function getImages()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Image::className(), ['category_id' => 'id']);
    }
}
```

Подробнее в [официальной документации](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#relational-data)

Comment: официально в документации написано следующее
Вы можете жадно загрузить более глубокие вложенные связи, такие как a.b.c.d. Все родительские связи будут жадно загружены.Таким образом, когда вы вызываете метод [[yii\db\ActiveQuery::with()|with()]] с параметром a.b.c.d, вы жадно загрузите связи a, a.b, a.b.c и a.b.c.d. в чем отличее  этого 'goods.images' от этого a.b ?

Comment: @Sergalas У Вас отсутствует метод *getImages()*. Читайте внимательно и не хейтите ссылки на офф. документацию.

Comment: @Makarenko_I_V а ответьте пожалуйста если я делаю жадную вложеную загрузку зачем мне делать метод getImages() в Category есть он есть в Gods и найдите мне отличия пожалуйста у этого кода 
`$customers = Customer::find()->with('orders.items')->all();
// доступ к деталям первого заказа первого покупателя 
// SQL-запрос не выполняется
$items = $customers[0]->orders[0]->items;` и этого

Comment: @Makarenko_I_V и этого `$recomented=Category::find()->where(['name'=>$titleCat->value])->with('goods','goods.images','goods.prise','goods.addfeilds','goods.ratingCountAggregation','goods.ratingSumAggregation')->all();

if(isset($recomented)) {
    foreach ($recomented as $rec){
        var_dump($rec->goods);
    }
}` заисключением того что там массив вызывается по ключу а у меня foreach

Comment: Ну начнем с того, что у вас не этот участок кода выдаёт такую ошибку.